# How to make the countdown component display when website is loaded

Tags: reactjs, next.js, countdowntimer

I have an ongoing project and want to display a countdown before site lauch, how do I do this? Is it posible to load the main webpage when countdown == 0? How do I make the coundown component display when site is loaded?

I have created the component, and its working, but don't know how to make it display on site load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render conditionally Countdown or Main component depending on the countdown value. Something like this:

```
if (countdown !== 0) {
  return <CountDownComponent />
}

return <Main />
```